# Transformer very basic questions

Tags: power-supply, transformer

Good day for all.

My question is about the power on a transformer and its functionallity. I know that the power is the same in both inductors (ideally),  if I've a source at 240V/10A then the power is 2400W, when the transformer output is 24V then the current up to 100A.

**First question**: If I have a circuit that work at 24V, 1A, It will be in fire for the high current?

**Second question**: If anyone (very tired with the life) took the output filaments, all the 100A current trip across his body and he is over forever?

Well, both questions are the same, I believe. The core is, albeit I've 100A, *Can I took only the necessary for my electronic component, always that it will be for 24V?, Is the output current value not important?*

Thanks.

Comment: A transformer producing 24 volts may be perfect for a load needing 24 volts at 1 amp, if the transformer can provide an output current of at least 1 amp. In this case, the transformer can provide 2 amps, and even 4 amps, and given a lower load resistance that needs 8 amps to satisfy Ohms Law the  transformer is safe in outputting 8 amps and even 16 amps and finally, safely, even that 32 and 64 and 100 amps which is the transformer rating.

Comment: Just calculate: I = U/R

Comment: Ohm's law must be one of the simplest, most fundamental, and yet most misinterpreted, relationships in engineering.

Answer (score 0):

You have the misapprehension that if the transformer can supply 100 amperes, it will do so to any connected load.  That is not true.  The load will draw only the current it requires.  If it is rated at 24V and 1A, then it will draw 1A when connected to the 24V transformer and no more.  If you touched the 24V secondary, then your body will not draw 100A because your internal resistance is much higher than needed to draw that much current (to draw 100A from a 24V source requires a resistance of 24/100 or less than 1/4 ohm). Your body resistance is on the order of thousands of ohms so the current draw will be only a few milliamperes and you will not be roasted.

Comment: Thanks Barry. It's clear now

Answer (score -1):

1. <strike>Yes, your circuit will stop working in a violent manner if the components used inside your circuit are not rated to handle 100A or more.</strike>

No, your circuit will still function. I forgot to recall that the ratings of a power supply usually indicate the **maximum** that it can provide at any moment. If your circuit draws 24V, 1A then it will ideally draw that much from the power supply.

2. Sadly, you won't be able to kill yourself. Although the current is extremely high, the voltage wouldn't really be high enough to sufficiently drive that current through your body due to the body's high skin resistance (assuming that the skin is dry and not wet). You can refer to these links for a similar scenario (with a much detailed explanation):

[Can a 12V battery give you a shock or not?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/189691/can-a-12v-battery-give-you-a-shock-or-not)

Comment: If the circuit is rated at 24V, 1A, what makes you think it will pass through 100A when you apply 24V to it?

Comment: No, the circuit will not be destroyed if it draws 1A from a source that is capable of providing 100A. The circuit will draw just as much current as it needs and the primary current will be reduced proportionally.

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev My bad! Forgot that the rating is only an indicator of the maximum current the source can supply. Did the necessary edits, apologies.